# How can I remove a click event from an element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a `<div>` element that has a click event attached to it using the following code:

```
var id = "someId";
var elem = document.getElementById("elemId");
elem.addEventListener("click", function() { someFunction(id); }, false);
```

At a later point I copy the element and add it to another part of the `DOM`, but need to first remove the `click` event

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elemId");
elem.removeEventListener("click", ???? , false);
```

I'm not sure how to reference the listener and so far nothing I have tried has removed the event from the element.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move the anonymous click handler function out of the `addEventListener` call:

```
var id = "someId";
var elem = document.getElementById("elemId");
var elemEventHandler = function() { someFunction(id); };
elem.addEventListener("click", elemEventHandler , false);
```

after which you should be able to:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elemId");
elem.removeEventListener("click", elemEventHandler , false);
```

Comment: The difficulty with this is there may be multiple elements with this EventListener in the DOM at any one time, each with thier own id value. As such I cant create a single global elemEventHandler variable. The code that adds the event listener takes place in its own function that the id is passed into. How can I get round this?

Comment: @Stewart. It's perfectly possible to reference the same handler for a number of elements, and remove that reference for one of them. I've cooked an example in jsfiddle to demonstrate that: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/qQv9K/ - in which you can also see how to retrieve the id of the clicked element, by the way

Comment: @Koolinc - thanks. Looks good, had a quick play around and still having some problems, but will put some more time into this later and update the thread then.

Comment: @Stewart: glad I could help. I've added an alternative to the jsfiddle, where the handler is added as property to the element itself. That way you can use paremetrized handler functions per element.

Comment: @Koolinc - Thanks, the paremetrized handler works a charm, except of course when I fire up IE8! Any ideas how I can make this cross browser compatable? Just using attachEvent instead of addEventListener for IE8 doesn't result in the event being attached to the element.

Comment: Ok, I've almost got it running in IE8- and current browsers by checking if browser supports addEventListener/removeEventListener and if not using attachEvent/detachEvent. This works in IE8 for attachEvent, so elem.attachEvent('onclick', elem.clickHandler) based on your example works fine. But I can't then detatch the event using elem.detatchEvent('onclick', elem.clickHandler || clickHandler)

Answer (score 7):

The answer above is correct.
However, in case, someone is looking to remove the `onclick` function which is attached to a button like this for eg

```
<button type="button" onclick="submit()" id="tour-edit-save">Save</button>
```

In this case, to remove the `onclick` attached function, one will have to remove the attribute `onclick` and that would work perfectly fine.
Here is how you would remove using pure `JavaScript`

```
document.getElementById('tour-edit-save').removeAttribute('onclick');
```

Using `jquery`

```
$('#tour-edit-save').removeAttr('onclick');
```

Hope this helps someone who's looking for this answer.